# Using stackoverflow data to look at trends in technology usage

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search, data-analysis

Is it possible to query how many questions per day have been asked on a particular subject on Stackoverflow over a period of time?

For instance, I can use [Google Web Trends](http://www.google.co.uk/trends/) to compare number of searches per unit time for different search terms, but often the results are skewed because I'm searching for a technology that shares the same name as something else. For instance, searching for 'java vs c#' on Google Web Trends would probably pick up quite a lot of noise as java is also a type of coffee, and c# is a musical note.

This could be a great way to look at what technologies are 'up and coming', and potentially what I should learn next.

Comment: One word: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Undo - You are more noble than I, leaving a comment.

Comment: Thanks guys - I've flagged this as a dupe.

Comment: I built a ui for visualizing this sort of thing here http://sotagtrends.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly what the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) is for.

---

**Edit:** [Here's a query I put together just now](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166418/number-of-questions-asked-per-week-given-a-specified-tag?Tag=regex), feeling guilty earning rep for such a trivial answer otherwise. It uses [this answer on grouping counts by week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429450/925913) as a reference.

```
DECLARE @Tag nvarchar(25) = '##Tag##';

SELECT
  COUNT(UniqueId), WeekStart
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    Posts.Id AS UniqueId, 
    dateadd(week, datediff(day, '20000109', Posts.CreationDate) / 7, '20000109') AS WeekStart  
  FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.Id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.Id = PostTags.PostId
  WHERE
    Tags.TagName = @Tag and
    Posts.PostTypeId = 1 -- Questions
) RelevantQuestionsByWeek
GROUP BY WeekStart;
```

for the tag [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) outputs:

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link.

Comment: @rcgeorge23 - I edited the answer to include a query you can start with.

Comment: Note that you can simply replace the `7` with any number you want (`30` for example), but to do month-by-month breakdowns you'll have to parse the middle two digits of dates, or find some other technique.